# how can i pass a object parameter from a servlet to a jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, parameters

the object i want to pass is a list of item, item class described below :

```
class item{
String val1
String val2
String val3
}
//with getter setters
```

How can i pass items ( List items = new ArrayList() ) from a servlet to a jsp page and what do i have to add in the jsp to access the object ?

Answer (score 2):

In the servlet you can store the object in the request scope.

```
     getRequest().setAttribute("items", items);
```

Where items is your ArrayList of items.

On the JSP page you can access it in a number of ways. For example, using JSTL:

```
 <c:forEach items="${items}" var="i">

     ${i.val1}
 </c:forEach>
```

Comment: just to add to Vincent's answer, you also need to provide the directive to include the JSTL core [also, the JSTL jar should be present in your webapp's classpath]

Answer (score 0):

In the servlet:

```
httpRequest.setAttribute("myItem", item);
```

then forward to the JSP, and then in the JSP:

```
${myItem}
```